# Convergence of $f_n(x)= \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$

Tags: calculus

I have a sequence of functions: $$f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$$

I use ratio test, for finding convergence:

$$\Large \lim \frac{\frac{x^{n+1}}{1+x^{n+1}}}{\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}}=\lim \frac{x(1+x^n)}{1+x^{n+1}}=\lim x\frac{x^n(1+1/x^n)}{x^n(x+1/x^n)}=\frac{x}{x}=1$$

The answer in a book is $x$. Where do I make an error?

Comment: The ratio test is great to test whether a series converges.  But, it doesn't tell you what it coverges to.  And, you don't have a series, you have a sequence

Comment: Do you understand what is ratio test?

Comment: You have told us the answer in a book is $x$. What is the question?

Comment: Note $\frac{x^n}{1+x^n} = \frac{x^n+1 - 1}{1+x^n} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+x^n}$, which will likely help in whatever it is you are trying to show.

Comment: I looks as if you have not even stopped to think about what are your trying to solve. What limit are you interested in? The limit, for each fixed $x$, as $n$ tends to $\infty$? Or the limit, for a fixed $n$, as $x$ tends to something?

Comment: I need to find on which interval series converge and the limit for each fixed $x$, as $n$ tends to infinity. Here is the answer and solved problem: http://www.math.uci.edu/~brusso/140bhwsol5.pdf